# dbcp jar added automatically into project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I'm working on a maven based web project. In one module that generates .war file i have some dependencies in POM file, some jars are added to WEB-INF/lib folder. i don't have added jar: `commons-dbcp-1.3.jar` into POM nor in lib folder, but when i build my project using maven, `commons-dbcp-1.3.jar` added .war file also i can view it to lib folder in target directory.
Can anyone help me to explain how this jar is being added to war or lib folder in target directory.

I have also checked the "build path" and this jar is not added as an external jar.

I'm using Eclipse(Indigo).

Here is the POM file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>rpt</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20131018</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mind</groupId>
            <artifactId>mind-common-framework</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <organization>
        <name>OrgName</name>
    </organization>
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-r${prefix.revision}</finalName>
                    <attach>false</attach>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Implementation-Build>${project.version}</Implementation-Build>
                            <Build-Time>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Time>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Do a `mvn dependency:tree` and see what it says about `DBCP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This jar can possibly be one of the dependencies for running your project and Maven automatically downloads and packages the required dependencies(jars) for the project at the time of compilation and packaging.
***DBCP commons jar is provided by Apache for maintaining the pool of connection objects*** . It is basically used in the applications involving database connections where many users can simultaneously try to access the DB(eg: Web Base Applications involving DB operations) to improve the performance of the application and the system.

If you don't wish to bundle this jar with your package and such a capability will be provided by the web container where your application will be deployed(connection pooling), you can set the **scope of this dependency to be 'provided'.**

Comment: may be you are right, but how to address these type of issues. I am having errors/exceptions on production but all OK on my local environment.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing due to this?

Comment: i my case jar is automatically added to lib folder without adding into pom file. Question is when i have not added this dependency to POM file how it was added to compiled war ?

Comment: Some of the dependencies defined in pom file might be having an internal dependency on this jar file and therefore it doesn't requires any explicit definition in the pom file and including this jar in your target folder is being taken care by Maven

Comment: how can i find these internal dependencies ... i just want to review all additional dependencies.

Comment: Check once the dependencies defined in your pom.xml and then research on which jars are the dependencies defined in pom.xml are internally dependent.Share your pom.xml.

Comment: can u plz check, just added POM file.

Answer (score 0):

The scope you should use for this is "provided". This indicates to Maven that the dependency will be provided at run time by its container or the JDK, for example.

Dependencies with this scope will not be passed on transitively, nor will they be bundled in an package such as a WAR, or included in the runtime classpath.

https://maven.apache.org/general.html#scope-provided

Comment: that's right, but for this i have to add the dependency to my pom file. but i my case jar is added to lib folder without adding into pom file. Question is when i have not added this dependency to POM file how it was added to compiled war ?

Comment: Some of the dependencies defined in pom file might be having an internal dependency on this jar file and therefore it doesn't requires any explicit definition in the pom file and including this jar in your target folder is being taken care by Maven